# Different ways to authenticate smartphone application like Android

Tags: android, security, authentication, ssl, pki

I am looking for different ways to authenticate client like android, iphone, windows and blackberry app and which one is better and why

As per my research I know of 2 way to authenticate client
1. Private key embedded inside smartphone app which will be used to sign the message : Problem with this is its easy for hacker to get access to private key 
2. Client certificate

Are there other ways to authenticate these smartphone app and which one is most secured?

Comment: This is actually one method - the client is authenticated not using the certificate but using private key of the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the options you list here are really the same. A client certificate is really just the public key part of a private/public keypair that is signed by some entity along with some identification information.

The best way to authenticate the client is to use mutually authenticated SSL. You can use self-signed certificates here so you don't need to buy any from a CA, assuming you control all of the clients that you want to allow access and you control the servers they are going to talk to. This will ensure that your clients only receives data from your legitimate server (configure the SSL system for your application to only accept the self-signed certificate that your server is using) and your server only accepts data from your authorized clients (configure your server to only access the self-signed certificates deployed in your app as a resource for client authentication). There is a complete step-by-step rundown on how to do this for Android in [Application Security for the Android Platform](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022596.do), published by O'Reilly.

You are correct in that you need to embed some secret information (a private key) in your client application and an attacker will be able to compromise it. The best solution you have within Android right now is to put the certificate and private key in a Keystore that you include in your application APK as a resource and have your application access the Keystore when it needs to use the key. That means your application will need to have the password to the Keystore. So, how you protect that password becomes important. You can obfuscate your code to make it harder for an attacker to determine that password, but that will only slow down a determine attacker who is reverse engineering your application. However, short of requiring the user of the device to type that password in every time they want to use your application, that's the best you can do. If your client app that is running on the device needs access to something that it stores, a person with access to that device will be able to access it as well. All you can do it make it more difficult.

Comment: Thank you very detailed answer, As part of complete solution what do you recommend one should do if the client certificate gets hacked?

Comment: There is not too much you can do except deploy a new client APK to your authorized clients and then configure the server to no longer trust the old client certificate.